# How do I loop through the results of a SELECT statement sql and use the result for stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to use the result of a select query into a stored procedure by using cursor but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @NumberPhone varchar(50)
DECLARE CUR CURSOR STATIC FOR

SELECT  MobilePhone
FROM info_client

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NumberPhone 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     DECLARE @return_value int, @idCli int, @sCode varchar(2)

     EXEC   @return_value = StoredP_Test
            @sLignePhone = @NumberPhone,
            @sIMEI ='00000000000000000',
            @idCli = @idCli OUTPUT,
            @sCode = @sCode OUTPUT

    SELECT @idCli as N'@idCli',
           @sCode as N'@sCode'  

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NumberPhone 

    SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
END

CLOSE CUR 
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

This code duplicate the same result as the number of line of the select query.

Comment: Which procedure are you trying to EXEC? Missing the name?

Comment: You're using `@NumberPhone` in the first round, but `@sLigneAssValue` for the rest

Comment: Maybe you don't need a cursor at all? Depending on what that procedure is doing a cursor is very likely just way to slow this process down.

Comment: PLEASE don't start coding sql server like.  PLEASE.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an initial fetch of

```
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NumberPhone
```

Your code has a fetch next inside the loop

```
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @sLigneAssValue
```

Didn't you want to fetch next into the `@NumberPhone` variable?

The `@NumberPhone` variable will never change.

Comment: I made an error when i post my code that why , i have tow varibale and not the same but i edited my code et i chganged it.
The problem is : the result of executed procedure is always the same result because it passed to the procedure the numberphone of the first row selected and it didn't pass to the next row etc